# Firefox TextArea does not scroll without scrollbars

Tags: firefox, textarea, scrollbar

I am using `TextArea` tags in my web project, that shall never show scrollbars.
This can easily be accomplished using

```
TEXTAREA { overflow: hidden }
```

All browsers that I need (IE, FF, Chrome) hide the scrollbars, as intended.

However Internet Explorer and Chrome will scroll to the current cursor position anyway, while Firefox does not scroll anymore at all. You can move the cursor into the invisible area and type, but you will not see, what you are doing.

Can this be solved?

Regards,
  Steffen

EDIT: Because I have not found the source of the problem and I would really like to solve this, I leave this question open. However I found a really bad workaround: We now use `overflow: scroll` on that `TEXTAREA`, put it into a `DIV`, measure the width and height of the horizonal and vertical scrollbars, increase the size of the `TEXTAREA` by that values and set `overflow:hidden` to the `DIV` effectivly clipping away the scrollbars. They get invisible to the user but Firefox still scrolls. Not nice but working.

Comment: Why would you prevent the expected behaviour from happening?

Comment: Because we have our own (javascript based) scrollbar attached.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons but it's generally considered bad design to re-impliment this kind of functionality that users are so acustom to.

Comment: I know. However we have several other components that simply don't exist in HTML so we have do build those ourselfes. They work well and look nice together until we need a multi line input. If a add a plain `TEXTAREA` that works but simply does not fit into the layout... Having different styles of components within a singe application is a bigger no-go for me as offering something own. Moreover our components look the same on every operating system and look like native components on one of them...

Comment: "They get invisible to the user but Firefox still scrolls. Not nice but working." Try your textarea in Chrome/Safari and press the `Page Up` and `Page Down` on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Firefox is behaving as I'd expect given the semantics behind `overflow:hidden`.

That said, and having read your comments above, you can quite easily mimick the behaviour you want with a small bit of jQuery.

Here's the code I've written:

```
$('textarea').bind("focus keyup", function(){
    var $current = $(this);
    $current.scrollTop(
        $current[0].scrollHeight - $current.height()
    );
});
```

This will basically scroll the textarea to the bottom when you focus on it and as you type. It may need tweaking to account for edits being done further up in the content.

Here's a [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cTvzs/)

Comment: I thought about such a workaround as well, but I could not find a way to scroll to the current selection. Always scrolling to the bottom is not a good idea if there are lots of lines. Without being able to scroll to the input position (and in a way the user expects it, that is only scroll as fas as required, i.e. dont force the cursor to be on the topmost line all the time) we don't want to push that to our users.